# RXJS Observable enum type, Type 'Observable<Type>' is not assignable to type 'Type'

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to observe the latest event that happens in a stream. Each event can be one of two types, represented by an enum. However I am getting a compilation error in the following example:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';


export enum FilterAction {
  RESET, UPDATE
}

export class FilterSomething {

  private _filterEvent: BehaviorSubject<FilterAction> = new BehaviorSubject(FilterAction.RESET);

  get filterEvent() {
    return this._filterEvent.asObservable(); // <-- behave.ts(14,12): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<FilterAction>' is not assignable to type 'FilterAction'
  }


  set filterEvent(action: FilterAction){
    this._filterEvent.next(action);
  }
}
```

Compilation error:
`behave.ts(14,12): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<FilterAction>' is not assignable to type 'FilterAction'`

However when I use the generic `any` it compiles (and works).

```
set filterEvent(filterAction: any) {
   this._filterEvent.next(filterAction);
}
```

I suspect it's something to do with the enum values, as opposed to instances of `FilterAction`.

Comment: Which line is line 14?

Comment: `return this._filterEvent.asObservable();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is return type of your `getter`. `Getter`s and `Setter`s should take and return same type of parameter, which is `FilterAction` in your case. But your `getter` returns `Observable<FilterAction>`. Just do not use `getter`, change the name of the function. Then language service stop showing error. In language specification:

> If both accessors include type annotations, the specified types must be identical.

You can check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#45-object-literals) out.